# xml2js + Nuxt, how to use it?

Tags: nuxt.js, xml2js

I'm using axios to get an XML file. That works fine. I'm receiving a string. Then, I wanto to convert it to JSON whit xml2js. But everything I've tried hasn't worked. Any thoughts on that?